# Circle method way to count solutions to inequalities?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, inequality, complex-integration

I know the circle method can be used to count solutions to equations in a set. For example, if $P$ is the set of prime numbers and $eq_n$ is the equation $x^2+y^2=n$ then the solutions of $eq_n$ with $x,y\in P$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ can be counting using the fact that
$$\int_0^1 e(\alpha h)\,d\alpha$$
equals $1$ when $h=0$ and equals $0$ otherwise. Taking $h=(p_1^2+p_2^2)-n$ for primes $p_1,p_2$ we get that the number of solutions is
$$\sum_{p_1\;\text{prime}}\;\sum_{p_2\;\text{prime}}\int_0^1 e(\alpha(p_1^2+p_2^2-n))\,d\alpha=$$
$$=\cdots=$$
$$=\int_0^1 F(n)e(-\alpha n)\, d\alpha$$
for some function $F$.

Now lets say I want to count the number of solutions to $x^2+y^2<n$. In the same way that computing
$$\int_0^1e(\alpha h)\,d\alpha$$
tells us whether $h=0$ or not, is there a similar integral or formula that tells us if $h\ge 0$ or not? A function $G$ of $h$ which equals 1 only if $h\ge 0$ ?

Would a function $f$ defined as
$$f(h)=0\quad\text{if }h\ge 0$$
$$f(h)=x\quad\text{if }h<0$$
work? Maybe a smoother function ($e^{-1/x} type)$ is better?

Thanks!

Comment: What is this function $e(t)$ that you are using to define your integral? It obviously is not the exponential function, since $\int_0^1 e^{\alpha h}\,d\alpha \ne 0$ when $h \ne 0$. What function is it?

Comment: @PaulSinclair it is $e(x)=exp(2\pi i x)$

Answer (score 1):

I found a pretty neat answer: I realized that
$$h\ge 0\implies\exists d\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}\quad\text{such that}\quad h=d$$
(crazy)

And, because
$$\int_0^1 e(\alpha(h-d))\,d\alpha$$
is $=1$ iff $h=d$, and $h$ can only be equal to one and only one $d$ we have that
$$\sum_{d=0}^\infty\int_0^1 e(\alpha(h-d))\,d\alpha$$
is equal to $1$ iff the integral is $=1$ for some $d=0,1,\dots$ iff $h=d$ for some $d=0,1\dots$ iff $h\ge 0$.

I am yet to prove rigorously that the sum and integral can be interchanged so that
$$\int_0^1e(\alpha h)\sum_{d=0}^\infty e(-\alpha d)\,d\alpha=\int_0^1e(\alpha h)\frac{e(\alpha)}{e(\alpha)-1}\,d\alpha$$
is equal to one iff $h\ge 0$ and 0 otherwise. (Maybe the simplification of the sum is wrong but the details are not important)

**EDIT:** As Paul observed in his comment, the series
$$\sum_{d=0}^\infty e(-\alpha d)$$
doesn't converge. However, I realized that, for my particular problem, I don't need to sum from $d=0$ to $\infty$ but to a finite $D$, so the sum
$$\sum_{d=0}^D e(-\alpha d)$$
can be used instead without problems (and without justifying thesum-integral interchange)

Comment: $\sum_{d=0}^\infty z^d = \frac z{1-z}$ only works if $|z|<1$. Otherwise it diverges. But $|e^{-2\pi i\alpha}| = 1$. And that detail is crucial.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks for noticing. I actually don't need to check every non-negativa $h$ because I obtained an upper bound on its magnitude. Edit made